# How can I set a web page as my wallpaper in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop-customization

How can I put a web page as my background in Windows 10?

Active desktop doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

There are many third party applications available for different versions of windows that can act as a replacement for Active Desktop.

One example is [Plastuer](http://plastuer.com).

It should work for vista and up since it uses windows areo to replace your current wallpaper.
It says on their site that they use chromium to render the web pages.

Comment: There is also [WallpaperWebpage](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/WallpaperWebPage.shtml), which is free, but limited - eg. the page I wanted has Javascript that doesn't work in it.